# Can't access resource directory in appcelerator in iPhone device

Tags: iphone, filesystems, device, appcelerator

I have a lib folder inside the resource directory containing some js file. On iPhone simulator this code works fine and show all the folders and files inside it. But when deploying to the device it shows an error stating that `dirItems` is an `undefined`.

```
    var dirFullPath = Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + Ti.Filesystem.separator + 'lib';
    var dir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(dirFullPath);
    var dirItems = dir.getDirectoryListing();
    Ti.API.info(dirItems.length);
```

for your reference: Titanium: 2.1.3GA iOS:6.0

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the iphone folder is not accessible in real app.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Filesystem_Access_and_Storage) the Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory is read-only on a device, but is read/write in the simulator/emulator. Perhaps this circumstance causes an error when accessing a file or directory inside of the resourcesDirectory.

Why not using the Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory ?